# Error en Gradle al crear proyecto en Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola a todos venía trabajando bien desde la versión 2.3.3 pero al actualizar al nuevo android studio 3.0 me genera error al crear o abrir un proyecto, ya he intentado muchas formas de resolverlo, desde desactivar la opción de offline work hasta desinstalarlo e instalarlo nuevamente, me encuentro desesperado ya que llevo días tratando de resolverlo pero no logro hacerlo, anexo mis configuraciones de gradle.

[image: Error al compilar gradle]

[image: Gradle app]

[image: Gradle project]

Comment: Yo creo que ambos son importantes ¿No? Ashley G. ya que una solución certera no se puede dar con poca información.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDominguezGarcia ¿Qué más información se necesita para detallar éste error?

Comment: Mira aqui un probla similar al tuyo https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977185/6451314

Comment: Hola Carlos, en el caso de código o archivos de configuración es recomendable agregar texto no imagen, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** , saludos!

Comment: @JoseAntonioDominguezGarcia debes diferenciar entre el uso de complemento mediante imágenes y el problema en si, las imágenes son para complementar en su mayoría, para su mejor comprensión la base debe ser a texto.

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso lo solucione actualizando el SDK de Android.

Lo puedes hacer siguiendo estos pasos:

1. Ir al SDK Manager
2. Eliminar la versión 26.0.2 si la tienes y si no descargarla

   **NOTA: Si no te deja descargar, cambia el nombre de la carpeta como en la imagen**

   [image: Aquí cambie el nombre de la versión 26.0.2 y eso arreglo el problema]
3. Invalida el caché y reinicia
4. Prueba nuevamente

PDA: Esto me funciono a mí.

Comment: Hola jose, podrías mejorar tu respuesta añadiendo los pasos, para que tu respuesta sea completa. asi nos ayudamos entre todos y a lo usuarios nuevos en android.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDominguez agrega más información a tu respuesta!, revisa  [answer].

Comment: Yo no creo que requiera mas explicación ya que actualizar el SDK es algo relativamente sencillo. Ademas la imagen que les agregue es para que vean como queda el mío. No en todos los casos siempre es lo mismo, por eso agregue EN MI CASO.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente es importante notar que tienes definido en tu proyecto:

```
   compileSdkVersion 26
```

y

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Por lo tanto debes instalar este SDK!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La versión mínima para `Android Studio 3.0+` de `Gradle`, definida en tu archivo `build.gradle` debe ser `3.0.0`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


    }
}
```

**Si realizaste una actualización a Android 3.0 no olvides realizar la invalidación de caché en Android Studio y reiniciar.**

`File` > `Invalidate Cache / Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]